# When and in what language were certain programming features introduced?

Tags: language-features, history, language-design

Programming has come a long way. I am still relatively young (first Computer: C64), hence I take many things in programming for granted that were obviously introduced at some point and facilitated ways of programming that are now commonplace.

What follows is a (by no means complete) list of features, where I would love to know in which language and when they were introduced:

- introduction of functions
- compiled language
- interpreted language
- conditional & loop structures
- the array
- the dictionary (Hashtable)
- allowance of multi-threading
- functional programming (functions as data)
- object orientation (do we need to be more specific? maybe inheritance was there earlier than interfaces?)
- generics
- aspect-oriented programming
- meta-programming

If you can, try to back up your statement with some reference. If you feel I have missed an important programming language feature whose introduction should also be appreciated, please comment on this question such that it can be added to the list.

**UPDATE:**
I suppose that a programming language cannot introduce anything that wouldn't be possible in assembler, I'm rather looking for languages that made a certain feature available to "mere mortals".

Comment: It has to be said: http://james-iry.blogspot.com/2009/05/brief-incomplete-and-mostly-wrong.html

Comment: @Frank, just click "edit" then check "Community Wiki" checkbox just below edit area.

Comment: I think you can have object orientation without inheritance and interfaces.

Comment: @Stobor: That made my morning :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lisp. 1958.

Alternatively,

- introduction of functions - Alonzo Church's lambda calculus, 1930
- compiled language - Grace Hopper, 1952
- interpreted language - Lisp, 1958, maybe something before.
- conditional & loop structures - Bletchley Park Bombe 1940s ( ran in a loop ). Jacquard, 1801
- the array - as a contiguous chunk of memory with an index, Bletchley Park or Manchester Baby, 1940s
- the dictionary (Hashtable) - ?
- allowance of multi-threading - Jacquard, 1801; Multix 1965
- functional programming (functions as data) - Godel, 1930s
- object orientation

  - Simula ( Dahl and Nygaard 1967 ) for class based OO with inheritance
  - CLU ( Liskov 1975 ) iterators had a common interface, and allowed abstract data types with encapsulated state and behaviour
  - Smalltalk ( Kay late 1970s ) 'everything is an object'
  - Eifell ( Meyer 1986 ) design by contract influenced Java's `interface`s
- generics - generic methods ( Lisp again ) or parametric types ( modula??? )?
- aspect-oriented programming - common lisp meta-object protocol, late 1980s
- meta-programming - lisp macros, sometime in the 50s or 60s

Comment: That Jacquard joke is brilliant!

Comment: Just two minor quibbles: there is no such thing as a compiled language or an interpreted language. Whether someone uses a compiler or an interpreter to implement a language is an internal implementation detail of that specific language implementation and has nothing whatsoever to do with that language. Case in point: the vast majority of Lisp implementations are actually compiled.

Comment: @Jorg: You have a fair point, but I think the terms are still valid. According to the oracle Wikipedia, there are too: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiled_language and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreted_language

Comment: I'd remove SmallTalk. Simula was clearly the first, and defined the word "class".

Answer (score 4):

To the best of my knowledge (and with the help of Wikipedia), I would state the following:

- **Functions** - Early [Assembly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language), using instructions such as "jump to subroutine".
- **Compiled language** - Arguably [A-0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-0_programming_language) in 1952 or [FORTRAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FORTRAN in 1957.
- **Interpreted language** - [Smalltalk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk) (?) in the 1970s.
- **Conditional & Loop structures** - Early [Assembly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language), using branches/jumps.
- **Arrays** - Used in the very earliest computers (1940s). Appeared as a language feature in [FORTRAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FORTRAN). See [this text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure#History).
- **Hashtable** - Around the same time as arrays, since it only really uses a basic algorithm on top of an array data structure. As a class, perhaps `Dictionary` in [Smalltalk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk).
- **Multi-threading** - This is moreover a feature of the operating system/a library, though language features can of course facilitate multithreaded coding. It probably dates back to the 1960s/1970s, though, and I'd imagine it could be done in Assemby.
- **Functional programming** - [LISP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_programming_language) in the 1950s, inspired by Alan Turing's [lambda calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus).
- **Object orientation (OOP)** - [Simula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simula) in the 1960s.
- **Generics** - [CLU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CLU_programming_language) in the 1970s.
- **Aspect-oriented programming** - Perhaps [AspectJ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AspectJ) in 2001. (Someone may need to correct me on this.)
- **Meta-programming** - Early [Assembly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language), with self-modifying code.

Please feel free to modify/update this with any additional information.

Comment: Smalltalk appeared in 1980, and was preceded by interpreted BASIC and APL, among others. Lambda calculus due to Churce & Kleene.

Comment: The first interpreted language was probably Lisp, with BASIC in the mid-sixties also earlier than Smalltalk.

Comment: The earliest hashtable which could be considered part of the language (as opposed to implemented by the user) might be Smalltalk's Dictionary class.

Comment: @starblue: You're quite possibly right, but do you have any sources for that?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a language graph here: http://www.levenez.com/lang/ and Wikipedia to find answers. For starters: functions, loops and conditionals are with us since Fortran. And then, in 1958 Lisp arrived, I think some will argue that the rest came then :)

Comment: Nice chart. That's gonna go on my wall here in the office :)

Answer (score 1):

Finding firsts always leads to hair splitting.  I'll bet any of the things you mentioned were done several times over before they hit the big time.  Nonetheless, here's an attempt:

- functions -- FORTRAN, but not recursive.  LISP or Algol for recursion.
- compiled language -- FORTRAN
- interpreted language -- LISP
- conditional and loop structures -- FORTRAN, but Algol gave us structure programming
- the array -- FORTRAN
- the dictionary -- Snobol, I think
- allowance of multi-threading -- PL/I
- functional programming -- LISP but perhaps not in a strong sense.
- object orientation -- Simula but Smalltalk was the real popularizer
- generics -- dunno
- aspect-oriented -- dunno
- meta-programming -- perhaps C++, but then code generating code isn't a new idea

Answer (score 0):

I think we can safely say "assembler". Most if not all of these concepts have been around for a very long time.

Comment: Assembler does not have any of these features!

Comment: The question was when were these features introduced. And they were introduced in assembler programs in the 1950s.

Comment: Object orientation? Meta programming? Generics? I don't think you can say any of these applied (or currently do apply) to assembler.

Comment: Well, I was certainly writing OO code in assembler in the late 70s. Generics - assemblers have powerful macros (more like LISP macros than C) for this. Meta-programming - ever heard of self-modiying code?

Comment: Indeed, you're right about meta-programming. I'm still very doubtful about OOP and generics in Assembly however.

Comment: Polymorphism (aka OOP) has always been used in assembler, in the form of pointers jump tables. There was a huge discussion on comp.object about this a while back.

Comment: deffo. If the ptr is not polymorphism at its core I don't know what is.

Comment: There doesn't even exist a concept of objects/classes/types in assembler, let alone inheritance. These things are at the core of OOP in my view.